# Accept URL as parameter in path (special characters)

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view and a `path` where I'd like to accept a str parameter and pass it to my `make_request` view.

The problem I'm having is the strings I'd like to accept are URLs. When I pass a string like 'https://example.com/' I get an error saying `Page not found (404)` as there are special characters.

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:url>', views.make_request, name='make_request'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def make_request(url):
    print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out.

The solution was to use the `path` converter.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<path:url>', views.make_request, name='make_request'),
]
```